# how to echo tab delimited in csh script

Tags: echo, csh

I have a csh script and no matter what I do it never echoes the right tab space.
This is what i want:

```
header 1    header 2    header 3    header 4
```

Case 1:

```
echo header 1 header 2 header 3 header 4 | tabify
```

Output: It will replace all spaces to tab

Case 2:

```
echo "header 1\\theader 2\\theader 3\\theader 4"
```

or

```
echo header 1\\theader 2\\theader 3\\theader 4
```

Output: header 1\\theader 2\\theader 3\\theader 4

Case 3:

```
echo -e "header 1\\theader 2\\theader 3\\theader 4"
```

Output: -e header 1\\theader 2\\theader 3\\theader 4

Help? T.T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CShell sucks, but printf will save the day once more.

```
$ printf 'header 1\theader 2\theader 3\n'
header 1    header 2    header 3
```

(Please ignore Stack Overflow's inability to show tabs)

Comment: I'm going to have to go with "because tcsh is a bad shell and has a bad built-in implementation of echo".